# file xml put in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I wrote code in order to put data read from file to a datagridview.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDataDocument xmlsach = new XmlDataDocument();
            xmlsach.DataSet.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + "\\cm_exp_20170712_221837.xml");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = xmlsach.DataSet;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "ExternalUtranCell";

        }
```

But it only shows id of ExternalUtranCell, I want to show everything put in only one table. How can I achieve this?
Here is a part of my table definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns:un ="abc" xmlns:xn="def" xmlns:es="ghi">
<un:ExternalUtranCell id="12345-16-11">
  <un:attributes>
    <un:rac>11</un:rac>
    <un:lac>11</un:lac>
    <un:primaryCpichPower>300</un:primaryCpichPower>
    <un:primaryScramblingCode>0</un:primaryScramblingCode>
    <un:uarfcnDl>10588</un:uarfcnDl>
    <un:uarfcnUl></un:uarfcnUl>
    <un:mnc>45</un:mnc>
    <un:mcc>123</un:mcc>
    <un:rncId>16</un:rncId>
    <un:cId>11</un:cId>
    <un:userLabel></un:userLabel>
  </un:attributes>
  <xn:VsDataContainer id="12345-16-11">
    <xn:attributes>
      <xn:vsDataType>vsDataExternalUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
      <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes.16.28</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
      <es:vsDataExternalUtranCell>
        <es:individualOffset>0</es:individualOffset>
        <es:maxTxPowerUl>100</es:maxTxPowerUl>
        <es:qQualMin>100</es:qQualMin>
        <es:qRxLevMin>100</es:qRxLevMin>
        <es:agpsEnabled>1</es:agpsEnabled>
        <es:cellCapability>
          <es:hsdschSupport>0</es:hsdschSupport>
          <es:edchSupport>0</es:edchSupport>
          <es:edchTti2Support>0</es:edchTti2Support>
          <es:enhancedL2Support>0</es:enhancedL2Support>
          <es:fdpchSupport>0</es:fdpchSupport>
          <es:multiCarrierSupport>0</es:multiCarrierSupport>
          <es:cpcSupport>0</es:cpcSupport>
          <es:qam64MimoSupport>0</es:qam64MimoSupport>
        </es:cellCapability>
        <es:transmissionScheme>0</es:transmissionScheme>
        <es:parentSystem>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,vsDataExternalUtranPlmn=1</es:parentSystem>
        <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>
        <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>1</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
        <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>2</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
        <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>3</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
        <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>4</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
        <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>7</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
        <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSupport>0</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSupport>
        <es:srvccCapability>1</es:srvccCapability>
        <es:reportingRange1a>0</es:reportingRange1a>
        <es:reportingRange1b>0</es:reportingRange1b>
        <es:timeToTrigger1a>-1</es:timeToTrigger1a>
        <es:timeToTrigger1b>-1</es:timeToTrigger1b>
        <es:rimCapable>0</es:rimCapable>
        <es:lbUtranCellOffloadCapacity>1000</es:lbUtranCellOffloadCapacity>
      </es:vsDataExternalUtranCell>
    </xn:attributes>
  </xn:VsDataContainer>
</un:ExternalUtranCell>
  <un:ExternalUtranCell id="12345-16-11">
    <un:attributes>
      <un:rac>11</un:rac>
      <un:lac>11</un:lac>
      <un:primaryCpichPower>300</un:primaryCpichPower>
      <un:primaryScramblingCode>0</un:primaryScramblingCode>
      <un:uarfcnDl>10588</un:uarfcnDl>
      <un:uarfcnUl></un:uarfcnUl>
      <un:mnc>45</un:mnc>
      <un:mcc>123</un:mcc>
      <un:rncId>16</un:rncId>
      <un:cId>11</un:cId>
      <un:userLabel></un:userLabel>
    </un:attributes>
    <xn:VsDataContainer id="12345-16-11">
      <xn:attributes>
        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataExternalUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
        <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes.16.28</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
        <es:vsDataExternalUtranCell>
          <es:individualOffset>0</es:individualOffset>
          <es:maxTxPowerUl>100</es:maxTxPowerUl>
          <es:qQualMin>100</es:qQualMin>
          <es:qRxLevMin>100</es:qRxLevMin>
          <es:agpsEnabled>1</es:agpsEnabled>
          <es:cellCapability>
            <es:hsdschSupport>0</es:hsdschSupport>
            <es:edchSupport>0</es:edchSupport>
            <es:edchTti2Support>0</es:edchTti2Support>
            <es:enhancedL2Support>0</es:enhancedL2Support>
            <es:fdpchSupport>0</es:fdpchSupport>
            <es:multiCarrierSupport>0</es:multiCarrierSupport>
            <es:cpcSupport>0</es:cpcSupport>
            <es:qam64MimoSupport>0</es:qam64MimoSupport>
          </es:cellCapability>
          <es:transmissionScheme>0</es:transmissionScheme>
          <es:parentSystem>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,vsDataExternalUtranPlmn=1</es:parentSystem>
          <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>
          <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>1</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
          <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>2</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
          <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>3</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
          <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>4</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
          <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>7</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport>
          <es:hsAqmCongCtrlSupport>0</es:hsAqmCongCtrlSupport>
          <es:srvccCapability>1</es:srvccCapability>
          <es:reportingRange1a>0</es:reportingRange1a>
          <es:reportingRange1b>0</es:reportingRange1b>
          <es:timeToTrigger1a>-1</es:timeToTrigger1a>
          <es:timeToTrigger1b>-1</es:timeToTrigger1b>
          <es:rimCapable>0</es:rimCapable>
          <es:lbUtranCellOffloadCapacity>1000</es:lbUtranCellOffloadCapacity>
        </es:vsDataExternalUtranCell>
      </xn:attributes>
    </xn:VsDataContainer>
  </un:ExternalUtranCell>
</root>
```

Comment: The method DataSet.ReadXml() uses the first tag as that DataSet name.  The second level tag is the DataTable Names.  The third level tags are the column names and the fourth level tags are the row data.  When you have more than 4 levels of tags the ReadXml() starts to split the data into many DataTables that are really unusable.  So you need to create a custom xml parser.  I've done this many times before.  In this case there are issue with the tag(s) hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport where you have 5 columns with same name.  Also you have namespaces that must be handled properly.

Comment: can you show me about code, i work about telecom and i begin to study C# about few months, my job request put data in datatable through C#, i know put in listbox but it don't require , thanks you

Comment: Can you post xml with more than one row?

Comment: what do you mean? i don't understand i just want to put all data in one table

Comment: A DataTable usually has more than one DataRow.  Your input has only one row.

Comment: i want to input more DataRow , one Datarow is not enough for my file xml 300MB, i wrote code use Datacolumn when i run it is nothing

Comment: I want to see what two rows look like in the XML. You only have one row.  I don't need to see 300MB.

Comment: i don't understand, i think one datatable have more datarow, example i have a lot of id, each id have more element, when i show input datatable each id is one row, you can show me your code thanks for your help

Comment: Show me what two rows look like in XML.  I cannot answer this request without you showing me what two rows look like.  I'm not going to answer any more comments without two data rows!!!

Comment: i create 1 datarow for ExternalUtranCell in order to show id after i create 1 datarow for attributesattributes i have two 2 datarow. am i right? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following.  I edited your xml to have valid xml.  You were missing namespaces :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\cm_exp_20170712_221837.xml";
        static DataTable dt;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));

                dt.Columns.Add("rac", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("lac", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("primaryCpichPower", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("primaryScramblingCode", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("uarfcnDl", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("uarfcnUl", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("mnc", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("mcc", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("rncId", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("cId", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("userLabel", typeof(string));


                dt.Columns.Add("vsDataType", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("vsDataFormatVersion", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("individualOffset", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("maxTxPowerUl", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("qQualMin", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("qRxLevMin", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("agpsEnabled", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("hsdschSupport", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("edchSupport", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("edchTti2Support", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("enhancedL2Support", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("fdpchSupport", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("multiCarrierSupport", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("cpcSupport", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("qam64MimoSupport", typeof(int));

                dt.Columns.Add("transmissionScheme", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("parentSystem", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("mncLength", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("hsAqmCongCtrlSupport", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("srvccCapability", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("reportingRange1a", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("reportingRange1b", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("timeToTrigger1a", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("timeToTrigger1b", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("rimCapable", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("lbUtranCellOffloadCapacity", typeof(int));

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
                XElement root = doc.Root;
                XNamespace unNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("un");
                XNamespace xnNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xn");
                XNamespace esNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("es");

                foreach (XElement cell in doc.Descendants(unNs + "ExternalUtranCell"))
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();

                    newRow["id"] = (string)cell.Attribute("id");

                    XElement attributes = cell.Element(unNs + "attributes");

                    if (((string)attributes.Element(unNs + "rac")).Length > 0) newRow["rac"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "rac");
                    if (((string)attributes.Element(unNs + "lac")).Length > 0) newRow["lac"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "lac");
                    newRow["primaryCpichPower"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "primaryCpichPower");
                    newRow["primaryScramblingCode"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "primaryScramblingCode");
                    newRow["uarfcnDl"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "uarfcnDl");
                    if (((string)attributes.Element(unNs + "uarfcnUl")).Length > 0) newRow["uarfcnUl"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "uarfcnUl");
                    newRow["mnc"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "mnc");
                    newRow["mcc"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "mcc");
                    newRow["rncId"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "rncId");
                    newRow["cId"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "cId");
                    newRow["userLabel"] = (string)attributes.Element(unNs + "userLabel");

                    XElement vsDataContainer = cell.Element(xnNs + "VsDataContainer");
                    XElement vsDataContainerAttributes = vsDataContainer.Element(xnNs + "attributes");

                    newRow["vsDataType"] = (string)vsDataContainerAttributes.Element(xnNs + "vsDataType");
                    newRow["vsDataFormatVersion"] = (string)vsDataContainerAttributes.Element(xnNs + "vsDataFormatVersion");

                    XElement vsDataExternalUtranCell = vsDataContainerAttributes.Element(esNs + "vsDataExternalUtranCell");

                    newRow["individualOffset"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "individualOffset");
                    newRow["maxTxPowerUl"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "maxTxPowerUl");
                    newRow["qQualMin"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "qQualMin");
                    newRow["qRxLevMin"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "qRxLevMin");
                    newRow["agpsEnabled"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "agpsEnabled");

                    XElement cellCapability = vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "cellCapability");

                    newRow["hsdschSupport"] = (int)cellCapability.Element(esNs + "hsdschSupport");
                    newRow["edchSupport"] = (int)cellCapability.Element(esNs + "edchSupport");
                    newRow["edchTti2Support"] = (int)cellCapability.Element(esNs + "edchTti2Support");
                    newRow["enhancedL2Support"] = (int)cellCapability.Element(esNs + "enhancedL2Support");
                    newRow["fdpchSupport"] = (int)cellCapability.Element(esNs + "fdpchSupport");
                    newRow["multiCarrierSupport"] = (int)cellCapability.Element(esNs + "multiCarrierSupport");
                    newRow["cpcSupport"] = (int)cellCapability.Element(esNs + "cpcSupport");
                    newRow["qam64MimoSupport"] = (int)cellCapability.Element(esNs + "qam64MimoSupport");


                    newRow["transmissionScheme"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "transmissionScheme");
                    newRow["parentSystem"] = (string)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "parentSystem");
                    newRow["mncLength"] = (string)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "mncLength");
                    newRow["hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport"] = string.Join(",", vsDataExternalUtranCell.Elements(esNs + "hsAqmCongCtrlSpiSupport").Select(x => (string)x));
                    newRow["hsAqmCongCtrlSupport"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "hsAqmCongCtrlSupport");
                    newRow["srvccCapability"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "srvccCapability");
                    newRow["reportingRange1a"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "reportingRange1a");
                    newRow["reportingRange1b"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "reportingRange1b");
                    newRow["timeToTrigger1a"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "timeToTrigger1a");
                    newRow["timeToTrigger1b"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "timeToTrigger1b");
                    newRow["rimCapable"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "rimCapable");
                    newRow["lbUtranCellOffloadCapacity"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "lbUtranCellOffloadCapacity");
                    newRow["agpsEnabled"] = (int)vsDataExternalUtranCell.Element(esNs + "agpsEnabled");
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\cm_exp_20170714_013357.xml";
        static DataTable dt;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));

                dt.Columns.Add("vsDataType", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("vsDataFormatVersion", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("localCellId", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("physicalLayerCellIdGroup", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("physicalLayerSubCellId", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("userLabel", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("tac", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("pciCell", typeof(string));
                //dt.Columns.Add("mcc", typeof(int));
                //dt.Columns.Add("mnc", typeof(int));
                //dt.Columns.Add("mncLength", typeof(int));
                //dt.Columns.Add("pciConflict", typeof(string));
                //dt.Columns.Add("enbId", typeof(int));
                //dt.Columns.Add("cellId", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("pciCellmcc", typeof(int));
                //dt.Columns.Add("pciConflictCellmnc", typeof(int));
                //dt.Columns.Add("pciConflictCellmncLength", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("earfcndl", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("lbEUtranCellOffloadCapacity", typeof(int));



                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
                XElement root = doc.Root;

                XNamespace xnNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xn");
                XNamespace esNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("es");


                DataRow newRow = null;
                XElement attributes = null;
                foreach (XElement cell in doc.Descendants(xnNs + "VsDataContainer"))
                {
                    attributes = cell.Element(xnNs + "attributes");
                    XElement vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD = attributes.Element(esNs + "vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD");
                    if (vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD != null)
                    {
                        List<KeyValuePair<string, XElement>> pciCells = vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Elements(esNs + "pciConflictCell")
                            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string,XElement>("conflictCell", x)).ToList();

                        pciCells.AddRange(vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Elements(esNs + "pciDetectingCell")
                            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, XElement>("detectingCell", x)).ToList());
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, XElement> pciCell in pciCells)
                        {
                            newRow = dt.Rows.Add();

                            newRow["id"] = (string)cell.Attribute("id");

                            newRow["vsDataType"] = (string)attributes.Element(xnNs + "vsDataType");
                            newRow["vsDataFormatVersion"] = (string)attributes.Element(xnNs + "vsDataFormatVersion");

                            newRow["localCellId"] = (int)vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Element(esNs + "localCellId");
                            newRow["physicalLayerCellIdGroup"] = (int)vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Element(esNs + "physicalLayerCellIdGroup");
                            newRow["physicalLayerSubCellId"] = (int)vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Element(esNs + "physicalLayerSubCellId");
                            newRow["tac"] = (int)vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Element(esNs + "tac");

                            //XElement activePlmnList = vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Element(esNs + "activePlmnList");

                            // newRow["mcc"] = (int)activePlmnList.Element(esNs + "mcc");
                            // newRow["mnc"] = (int)activePlmnList.Element(esNs + "mnc");
                            // newRow["mncLength"] = (int)activePlmnList.Element(esNs + "mncLength");


                            // if (((string)vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Element(esNs + "pciConflict")).Length > 0) newRow["pciConflict"] = string.Join(",", vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Elements(esNs + "pciConflict").Select(x => (string)x)); 

                            if (pciCell.Value != null)
                            {
                                if ((pciCell.Value.Element(esNs + "mcc") != null) && ((string)pciCell.Value.Element(esNs + "mcc")).Length > 0)
                                {
                                    newRow["pciCell"] = pciCell.Key;
                                    newRow["pciCellmcc"] = (int)pciCell.Value.Element(esNs + "mcc");
                                }
                            }

                            newRow["earfcndl"] = (int)vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Element(esNs + "earfcndl");
                            newRow["lbEUtranCellOffloadCapacity"] = (int)vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD.Element(esNs + "lbEUtranCellOffloadCapacity");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newRow = dt.Rows.Add();

                        newRow["id"] = (string)cell.Attribute("id");

                        attributes = cell.Element(xnNs + "attributes");

                        newRow["vsDataType"] = (string)attributes.Element(xnNs + "vsDataType");
                        newRow["vsDataFormatVersion"] = (string)attributes.Element(xnNs + "vsDataFormatVersion");
                    }


                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: i wrote code use 2 datarow above comment , how do you see?

Comment: Put break point at end of code.  Then hove over dt. There is a down arrow with DataVisualizer that will show table.

Comment: when i run it is error Input string was not in a correct format here newRow["rac"] = (int)attributes.Element(unNs + "rac"); and i have written new code use listview in this topic, i expect you will see it and feedback for me because it have error too, thanks you very much

Comment: You can take the datatable in my code above and bind it to a ListView or use it as the DataSource of a DateGridView.  Your new code will not work!!!!

Comment: but when i run your code it have error "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format" here "newRow["rac"] =(int)attributes.Element(unNs + "rac");"

Comment: You are using different xml than what is posted.  The error is caused by one of two reasons 1) unNs is null 2)  The tag ExternalUtranCell doesn't have an  element rac.  I suspect that unNs is null.  I is probably not defined in the first element in the xml file.

Comment: You did not verify the "unNs" is null.   I need ot know wghere the namespace 'un' is defined.

Comment: no my file xml have tag ExternalUtranCell have element rac but i have a new tag is SubNetwork and this tag have many  ExternalUtranCell with different id

Comment: this is my file you can download in here http://www.mediafire.com/file/2ecgyyp2rbcsrod/xml.zip   actually i still study from your code and i don't understand but i try to understand it, and again thanks for your help

Comment: There were a few cases where rac and lac did not have any numbers.  Modified code to handle these cases.

Comment: There are 100,898 rows in the datatable.

Comment: I changed code to a form project and put results into a DataGridView.  The code takes 30 seconds to run since the xml file is 340,000,000 bytes.

Comment: i have a new file and i wrote code for it but i don't understand when i delete command i can run but when i run with command it's nothing, i though about two day before ask you i don't find it , i expect you can show me its error http://www.mediafire.com/file/jq5if5h56xoa34u/Projects.rar thanks you

Comment: now, i can't find code in order to load tag "pciConflictCell" beacause it have may tag pciConflictCell with same name  , i can load tag "activePlmnList" i need replace int to string

Comment: See changes above

Comment: There is some invisible character in you code that is creating errors.  I was using VS2015 and was getting errors.  So I copied code into vs2010 and it ran fine.  Then I copied code back from vs2010 to vs2015 and error went away.

Comment: thanks you very much but can i load all mcc of tag pciConflictCell on newrow pciConflictCellmcc? because although the file have a lot of tag pciConflictCell but it is element of vsDataExternalEUtranCellFDD  i can find it at tag VsDataContainer id="L21-BKK3601-1C" it have a lot of pciConflictCell

Comment: when i run your code, it only load one "mcc" at pciConflictCellmcc

Comment: Each one is in a different row.

Comment: i understand thanks you very much but i have one tag else is pciDetectingCell, it look like tag pciConflictCell how i can load 2 tag, i try to write code in order to load but it can't

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           XmlReader xmlFile ;
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]
```

Comment: sorry i copy file xml error, i copyed it fully . thanks for your help but it is wrong

Comment: Which error you get? You want to show you full xml right ?

Comment: if i really get fully this file is about 300 MB i show fews code because it is same at ExternalUtranCell and diffirent id